# «Больше, чем обычно». Ставится ли запятая?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

«Предстоит работать больше, чем обычно». Я бы не поставила запятую, то есть «предстоит гораздо больше работать». А если опустить «чем», то получается чёрти что... значит, надо ставить знак препинания.

Answer (score 1):

**Предстоит работать больше, чем обычно.**

[Грамота:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68)

> Обороты, присоединяемые союзом «чем», выделяются (или отделяются)
>   запятыми, если в предложении называются или подразумеваются два
>   сравниваемых понятия.

А в предложении как раз берется за основу прошлый объем работы и сравнивается с предстоящим, затем делается вывод, что предстоит работать все-таки больше.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что возможны оба варианта (в том числе с точки зрения интонации):

(1) ***Предстоит работать бОльше, чем  (работаем) обЫчно.***

(2) ***Предстоит работать больше чем обЫчно*** (= много, больше обычного), так как нужно выполнить план.  Замена **оборота падежной формой** (Р.п.),

Такое построение (без обособления оборота) характерно для сложного предложения.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

4. Внутри сочетаний (не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем, (не) раньше чем, (не) позже чем и т. п., если они не содержат сравнения, **запятая не ставится:** Вы были для меня больше чем другом; К испытаниям он больше чем готов; Он был больше чем художник — он был поэт; Выпуск продукции увеличился больше чем вдвое; **Посылка весит не больше чем восемь килограммов (ср.: …не больше восьми килограммов);**